# with fully permissive iptables, tcpdump shows icmp echo requests arriving, but no reply's are sent

Tags: linux, networking, icmp

I'm a bit stumped on where to look next. When using SoftEther IPsec VPN into my network, I can access every server in the main subnet but one. When behind the main firewall, the server responds to all network traffic as expected. Please note, that the server in question has no iptables rules what-so-ever and all the chains are set to accept. But, when I am remote, and connect to the VPN, this server becomes inaccessible. I started looking at the VPN server, but it has no rules to prevent access. I can tcpdump packets on the VPN server and see requests going to the problem server, but no replies. When I ssh hop to the problem server and tcpdump, I can see the requests from the VPN client node, but for some reason or another, the problem server is not replying. hosts.deny is empty. Where else can I look to see where these requests are going? The node is older, running Linux 2.6.38.

Comment: Maybe the `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all` kernel setting?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tcpdump on the server itself when you try to reach it from the VPN (to make sure the trouble is on the server) ?

Answer (score 1):

Check routing *from* server to client - run on server:

```
ip route get <ClientIP>
```

It should display tunneling interface.